# Как отправить сообщение от лица аккаунта телеграм в группу с другими пользователями Python Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Как отправить сообщение от лица аккаунта телеграм в группу с другими пользователями Python Telethon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chat_id = '-100xxxxxx' 
client.send_message(chat_id, f"text")
```

docs:
tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/send_message.html